# spring - ApplicationContext registerBean autowiring fails but getBean works in Spring 5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm using a configuration class that uses dynamic bean registration:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass {

    @Autowired
    private GenericApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("init");
        applicationContext.registerBean("exService", ExecutorService.class, () -> Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10), bd -> bd.setAutowireCandidate(true));
        System.out.println("init done");
    }
}
```

If I try to autowire the bean, application startup fails with error `Field exService in com.example.DemoApplication required a bean of type 'java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService' that could not be found.`

From the logs I can see that the init method on config class wasn't called before the error as the two system out statements were not printed out.

However, when I use `applicationContext.getBean(ExecutorService.class)` it does work without any issues.

Anyway I can get the bean to Autowire?

I'm deliberately not using the `@Bean` annotation because I need to register the beans dynamically based on certain conditions.

Comment: Why do you want to register this bean? Why not just return it from the `@Bean`-annotated method?

Comment: If you add @Component annotation for ConfigClass , you will be able to autowire. Otherwise ConfigClass  is not a bean and how can you add dependency injection .

Comment: @lexicore: I'm writing a module for AWS where AWS clients will be created based on the regions configured in properties file. For example:
`aws.spring.s3.additional-regions=ap_south_1,us_east_1` I don't know in advance how many beans I've to create

Comment: @vipincp: Replacing `@Configuration` with `@Component` did not work.

Comment: @ares `@Configuration` is required . Along with that try `@component `as well

Comment: @vipincp both annotations together didn't work as well.

Comment: Spring has no way of knowing that `exService` is dynamically registred in your `@PostConstruct`. You need to tell it. You can create a component like MyDynamicBeansRegistrer, move your `@PostConstruct` there and then mark your `DemoApplication` with `@DependsOn`.

Comment: @chimmi you should extract this as an answer with a bit more explanation. See `Note that actual injection is performed through a BeanPostProcessor which in turn means that you cannot use @Autowired to inject references into BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor types. Please consult the javadoc for the AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor class (which, by default, checks for the presence of this annotation).` in the documentation for autowired here:https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

Comment: I dont see a reason for that, there is already an upvoted answer that covers `@DependsOn` approach as well as a better solution using `BeanFactoryPostProcessor `.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be because you are registering your bean in the middle of the context initialization phase. If your target bean initializes and auto-wires `ExecutorService` before `ConfigClass` `@PostConstruct` is invoked there simply is no bean available.

You can try forcing the initialization order:

```
@Component
@DependsOn("configClass")
public class MyComponent

  @Autowired
  private ExecutorService executorService;
```

However it would be cleaner to register a bean definition using `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` with `BeanDefinitionBuilder`:

```
@Component
public class MyBeanRegistration implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

  @Override
  public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory bf) {
    BeanDefinitionRegistry reg = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) bf;
    reg.registerBeanDefinition("exService",
      BeanDefinitionBuilder
        .rootBeanDefinition(ExecutorService.class)
        .setFactoryMethod("newWorkStealingPool")
        .getBeanDefinition());
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. this works. However, I want to keep the bean creation in an external jar and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` in external jars aren't scanned. I tried to run it by making it an autoconfiguration class and adding it to `spring.factories` but then it doesn't read any property from property file.

Comment: This is indeed a better solution. I think a quote from BeanFactoryPostProcessor docs explaining that it is applied before creation of any beans would be great for understanding how this works.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
@Resource
@Lazy
private ExecutorService executorService;
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wrote the small infrastructure that deals with such issues. Here is the idea how to  do this:

- Create a class (lets call it MyClass) that incapsulates ExecutorService.class as a property and declare it as Bean (@Component). Even before that create an Interface (Lets call it MyInterface) that your new class would implement
- Create a factory class (Lets call it MyFactory) with method MyInterface getInstance(String) that returnce an instance of your interface. In that factory crate a static property Map[String, MyInterface] and public static method that allows you to add instances of the interface to this map
- In MyClass create a constructor that at the end will place newly created instance of itself into that map in the factory with the key of your class name ("MyClass")

Now The trick is that when Spring starts and initializes it creates all its beans. As your MyClass will be created its constructor will place its instance into a factory. So now anywhere in your code you can call:

```
MyInterface myInterface = MyFactory.getInstance("MyClass");
```

And you get your bean without worrying about instantiating it. Spring already did it for you. Big extra bonus is non-intrucivness - you don't have to explicitely work with Spring classes

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of having DI. I agree that there are some cases when such approach is justified (e.g. accessing Beans from non Spring managed objects), but OPs issue is not one of them.

Comment: @chimmi I strongly disagree. First of all this approach works very well in Spring managed environment when you have a bean that has a propery of Interface that has several implementations that you don't know in advance which one you will need. Say you have a bean that has a property messageSender and based on runtime check you may need HttpMessageSender WebServiceMessageSender, SmsMessageSender or EmailMessageSender. So you don't know in advance what to inject. With my approach you have all those Beans in the Spring and a Factory (that is not Spring Specific) that allows you to get your class

Comment: @chimmi this is continuation of my previous comment: in OP case he can prepare his beans and not inject them anywhere but when he knows in runtime what he needs he can access them through non Spring Factory. So I think it is a very good option for OP. At least it doesn't deserve a vote down

Comment: My point was that OP specifically asked about autowiring (which can be done easily as I showed in my comment). But you suggested that they should drop DI and start resolving dependencies manually which, again, is not worth it in this case.

Comment: @MichaelGantman: It seems like a lot of work. If I have to get bean from a factory, why not do `applicationContext.getBean()`?

Comment: You can. The reason not to is that one of the principles of Spring is non-intucivness, which means that you should be able to write your code without using Spring specific classes, I.e. code that is not aware of Spring. I.e. once you configured everything then your code should be able to be free of any Spring related classes. Usually it is easy to achieve, except the case I described in my comment when you don't know in advance which implementation of an interface you will need in specific situation. And you will omly know at runtime

Comment: Continuation of previous comment: If you don't care for non-intrucive code then yes you can definitely use `applicationContext.getBean()`

Comment: However, if you are interested to keep your code non-intrucive let me know. I have a small infrastructure written that does everything I described above. I plan to add it into my own Open Source library that I have. Then you can just take my library and enjoy the effects without doing the coding